# ASP.NET Zero solution for both identityserver and client

Tags: identityserver4, openid, aspnetboilerplate, abp, aspnetzero

Before getting into the issue, let me tell you what I am trying to achieve.
I need to implement sort of SSO in all of my applications. For which I want to use **ASP.NET Zero** solutions as
SSO Provider as well as Clients.
Is it possible or am I overthinking?

I am using ASP.NET Zero template: ASP.NET Core - MVC & jQuery

I am very new to IdentityServer and OpenId so please excuse for my silly mistakes if I have made.

In one of ABP project, I have added a static client to IdentityServer AppSettings like below.

**First project's AppSettings** - Hosted application

```
  {
    "ClientId": "localhost",
    "ClientName": "MVC Client Demo",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [
      "implicit"
    ],
    "RequireConsent": "true",
    "ClientSecrets": [
      {
        "Value": "test"
      }
    ],
    "RedirectUris": [
      "https://localhost:44302/signin-oidc"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
      "https://localhost:44302/Account/Login"
    ],
    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "phone",
      "default-api"
    ],
    "AllowOfflineAccess": "true"
  }
```

Now from my second ABP project (localhost), I am trying to enable OpenId to authenticated through above server.

**Second project's AppSettings** - Running on localhost

```
"OpenId": {
  "IsEnabled": "true",
  "Authority": "https://[applicationname].azurewebsites.net/",
  "ClientId": "localhost",
  "ClientSecret": "test",
  "ValidateIssuer": "true",
  "ClaimsMapping": [
    {
      "claim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
      "key": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"
    }
  ]
}
```

However I am not getting any error, in logs I can see there is a message that says:

```
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
```

And a cookie is being created with key "Identity.External" but login-is not happening successfully.
Inside AccountController below line returns null and that resulting into unsuccessful login.

```
    **var externalLoginInfo = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();**
    if (externalLoginInfo == null)
    {
        Logger.Warn("Could not get information from external login.");
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Add("sub", ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

before *services.AddAuthentication()*

This will map **sub** claim to **NameIdentifier** claim so [GetExternalLoginInfoAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c56aa320c32ee5429d60647782c91d53ac765865/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L660) will not return null.

Comment: @gtermed - thanks for you response! issue seems resolved itself or because I added email scope option (options.Scope.Add("email")), I am unsure as I have a lot more changes here and there.. Thank you for your time!

Comment: And added this claim mapping..
        {
          "claim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
          "key": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
        }